# Set decoration for container in container

Tags: flutter, containers, decoration

> Error: Cannot provide both a color and a decoration To provide both,
> use "decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)".
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 274 pos 15: 'color == null || decoration == null'

```
Container(
      height: 250,
      child: PageView.builder(
        controller: _pageController,
        itemCount: listTmp.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), // <= Error here
              ),
              height: 100,
              child: Text(listTmp[index]),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          );
        },
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use `BoxDecoration()` remember to put the color parameter inside the `BoxDecoration()`.

```
child: Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), // <= No more error here :)
  color: Colors.red,
  ),
  height: 100,
  child: Text(listTmp[index]),
  ),
);
```

Comment: :)) I would like to have a container circular(10) inside an a container not circular. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't catch what you mean. Did you try my answer?

Comment: Oh..you put the color in container. Sorry I didn't realize. This code has run. Thank you so much! :))

Answer (score 2):

Always remember, when you use BoxDecoration to decorate containers, use the color property inside the BoxDecoration,

otherwise, will you face the error

Right Approach...!

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(078),
  color: Colors.red,
  ),
  child: Text('text'),
  ),
);
```

Wrong approach...!

```
Container(
 color: Colors.red,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(078),
  ),
  child: Text('text'),
  ),
);
```